# Edit user removes password - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to edit the data for one of my users. However, whenever I edit something, the passwords which are hidden, are also being changed and apparently set to null, which render the user unable to log in next time he wants to login. I know that I might have been able to solve the issue by using ViewModels, but im trying to do it without.

**Model**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{        
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email{ get; set; }
 }
```

Please notice that the User-class extends from IdentityUser which holds password variables.

**Edit in Controller**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,Email,PhoneNumber")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

**View for Edit**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

}

It is my understand that the Bind-parameter in the Edit-method either whitelist or blacklist the variables for editing. So for that reason i removed all of the values that shouldnt be edited by the user in Bind.

Comment: Why are *showing* the password hash to the user in the first place?  That has bad idea written all over it.  Never send a password (hashed or otherwise) to the browser.  Do you really need the user to be able to edit all of these hidden fields?  *SecurityStamp*? *LockoutEnabled*?  Only provide the fields that are needed for the user to make their changes, and then only update those fields in the data.  That is, instead of treating the incoming data as the entirety of a valid record, fetch the existing record into a separate variable and update only the fields that operation is meant to update.

Comment: @David. It's simly a scaffold which automatically does it. But Trust me, I also tried removing them. For some reason that gave me the exact same issue. So by using hidden fields i was hoping that the earlier values would be present in the hidden fields, which would potentially mean that the password wouldn't be changed. And as mentioned, I also know that using ViewModels would be better, but since this is my first ever .NET project, I know that for the next projects.

And no, I dont want the user to edit the hidden fields. Thats why i keep them hidden :)

Comment: You definitely shouldn't auto-generate a whole-record interface for sensitive data.  Again, only include the fields the user should be able to see/edit.  I can't imagine a reason to allow users to edit their own "locked out" status, or their *hashed* password.  Aside from that, the code of the issue is that you're treating the entire incoming view data as a whole and complete record, to replace an existing one.  Don't.  Fetch the existing one and edit only the fields meant to be edited.

Comment: *"I dont want the user to edit the hidden fields. Thats why i keep them hidden"* - You have misconceptions about the security of "hidden fields".  If you don't want the user to edit them, get rid of them entirely.  These are *easily* editable.

Comment: I can only say that I agree. If it helps, I have now removed all of the hidden values from the views. It still removes the password though, even though it's not a part of my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.  First, *don't present these fields to the user in the first place*.  I can't imagine a reason why a user should be able to edit their "locked out" status, or their *hashed* password.  Only include in the UI the fields which the user should actually be modifying.  Hell, even this has *horrible idea* written all over it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

You're not only allowing the user to edit *everything* about their user record, but you're also allowing them to *specify another user record* to edit.  So any user in the system can completely edit any other user in the system.

Hopefully you see how this is a bad thing :)

Now, you *can* (and often must) include the identifier in a hidden field.  The above problem is mainly bad because of what else you're doing:

```
db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

You are completely and implicitly trusting whatever the user sends you to be a whole, correct, and complete record for the database.  And replacing whatever existing record is there with whatever the user sends you.  That's... not good.

This approach can work for some models, but certainly not sensitive ones like user security data.

Instead, fetch the existing record and only edit the necessary fields.  Something like this:

```
var existingUser = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == currentUserId);
existingUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
existingUser.LastName = user.LastName;
// etc.
db.SaveChanges();
```

Notice that I used an otherwise undefined variable called `currentUserId`.  *Do not* use `model.Id`, because again that's allowing the user to specify which other user they want to edit.  Determing the current user ID by their current logged in session, not by what they send in the form.  However you currently identify your users.  (`User.Identity`?)

In short...

- Only let the user see/edit what they're allowed to
- Validate in the save action that the user is allowed to edit that data (*never* assume that they must be allowed to simply because they previously opened the page)
- Only update the values meant to be updated in that operation, don't just wholesale replace an entire record of sensitive data

Comment: Thats's a great answer! I think that updating individual values might solve my issue. For some reason i never thought of that. But thank you! I'll try it out and get back to you :)

Comment: @CodeProg: Probably the most important take-aways here are around not trusting information from the browser.  Hidden fields *can* be viewed and edited by the user, and users *can* post whatever data they want to any controller action they want regardless of whether or not they are "allowed" to view that page.  Never, ever implicitly trust what the user sends.  Always validate who that user is and what they are allowed to do.